# jQuery each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 3 rows and i am trying to loop through the table and get the title attribute for a link in each row of the table, assign it to a variable and put it into a function. Below is the code I am using:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
        //$('.distance').html("hello"); 
        //nodelat = $(this).find('.latitude').html();
        //nodelon = $(this).find('.longitude').html();

        postcode = $(this+".location a").attr('title');

        console.log(postcode);
        //$(this).find('.distance').html(distance(startlat, startlon, nodelat,nodelon));
    });
```

For some reason it seems to just repeat the value for the first table row 3 times. Am I missing something?

The code for the table is:

```
<table id="locations" class="tablesorter">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Distance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="location"><a href="#Dockyard" onclick="getLatLng(&quot;m502st&quot;, &quot;This is a pub&quot;)" title="m502st">Dockyard (show on map)</a></td>
      <td class="distance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="location"><a href="#Joseph Holt" onclick="getLatLng(&quot;M3 1JD&quot;, &quot;http://www.joseph-holt.com&quot;)" title="M3 1JD">Joseph Holt (show on map)</a></td>
      <td class="distance"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(this+".location a").attr('title');
```

To:

```
$(this).children('.location').children('a').attr('title');
```

Or:

```
$(this).find('.location > a').attr('title');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2rNH/).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this `$(this+".location a")` statement.

Try

```
postcode = $(this).find("td.location a").attr('title');
console.log(postcode);
```